# Two textblocks after each other

Tags: xaml, textblock

I have two textblocks and they are after each other on the page - name & surname. I am binding data to this so the size depends of the length of them. What's the best way to do them working with variable size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</StackPanel>
```